# Blazor Server - System.InvalidOperationException is throwing randomly

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm developing a application on Blazor Server (.NET 6). This exception occur a lot of times. But this exception occur in each page don't matter if the page render many times or not. For example, in a Login page (don't need to render more than once) this exception occur. I checked every event subscribe and all are unsubscribe when the dispose occur (so I think the event subscription is not a problem). I want to put my code as example but has more than 50k lines and you wouldn't want to read all the code.

I notice the application is a bit slow and would be by some Tasks or Threads running. If it is the problem what shall I do?

I read this exception occur when a Task ends more than once and I think is not the case.

If the `StateHasChanged` method is throwing this exception I have many `InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged).Wait()` and `await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged)` on the code. No too of these but some ones.

What I tried? I tried remove all the asynchronous methods that I could (removing the `await` and using a `.Result`). Also when dispose all `Callback += Method` is unsubscribed `Callback -= Method`. The application performance is very good less than 3% of all cores available is used.

```
Error: System.InvalidOperationException: An attempt was made to transition a task to a final state when it had already completed.
       at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1.SetException(Exception exception)
       at Microsoft.JSInterop.Infrastructure.TaskGenericsUtil.TcsResultSetter`1.SetException(Object tcs, Exception exception)
       at Microsoft.JSInterop.Infrastructure.TaskGenericsUtil.SetTaskCompletionSourceException(Object taskCompletionSource, Exception exception)
       at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime.EndInvokeJS(Int64 taskId, Boolean succeeded, Utf8JsonReader& jsonReader)
       at Microsoft.JSInterop.Infrastructure.DotNetDispatcher.EndInvokeJS(JSRuntime jsRuntime, String arguments)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RendererSynchronizationContext.<>c.<InvokeAsync>b__8_0(Object state)
    --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.CircuitHost.EndInvokeJSFromDotNet(Int64 asyncCall, Boolean succeeded, String arguments)
```

This exception don't broke the application. Only appear in the console and show the typical "An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details."

Comment: "exception don't broke the application" points to an `async void`. Avoid them as much as possible. And wrap their insides in a try/catch.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to be too complicated in your async code.  My guess is either:

1. You're using a `TaskCompletionSource` and setting it to complete when it is already set to complete.
2. Doing some JsInterop calls on completed tasks.

By complicated I mean:

```
InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged).Wait()
```

Why `.Wait()`?  rather than:

```
await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
```

It's hard to tell as there's no code.

Comment: I have multiples IJSRuntime executing some UI updates like ``await jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("ToggleSoundIcon", TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), value);`` but neither is using a ``.Result``. Also I tried changing every ``.Wait()` with `await`` and the problem persist. Now i'm thinking is a IJSRuntime issue on my implementation. In my code exists events that call IJSRuntime methods.

Comment: Every IJSRuntime is called and wrapped inside a trycatch so I think the exception couldn't show in the UI or can't stop the application because isn't a unhandled exception.